# Show/hide page content based on cookie from url parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to show some content on a page based on the parameter in a link.

If a link is given to a user https://www.examplesite.com/example-page/?client_feeback=1
then they will see the content of the page, if not using the link, then users will not see the content.

Additionally, I need the users of the link to be able to look on other pages and return to the page where the content is hidden/shown and still see the content.

I have set a cookie in functions.php, that will expire in 30days.

code added into functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'set_feedback_cookie'); 

function set_feedback_cookie () {
    $name = 'client_feedback';
    $value= 1;
    setcookie($name, $value, strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/example-page/", "examplesite.com", "true" );
}
```

I have then added the following into the example-page.php template file

```
<?php                   
    if (!isset($_GET['client_feedback'])) { ?>

    <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:none!important}</style>
<?php } else { ?>
    <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:block!important}</style>            
<?php } ?>
```

The cookie is loaded on to the site and the content is hidden/shown when using/ not-using the url link.

What is not working, is the ability to browse other pages on the site and come back to the page with the hidden content and still see it!

Comment: When you mean *"other pages"*, do you mean completely external pages that has absolutely nothing to do with your own website, or pages that are a part of your website, just not the current one in use? If it's all related to your own website, then a `session` variable would suffice.

Comment: also try `setcookie($name, $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/example-page/", "examplesite.com", "true");` The 86400 represents 1 day, so multiply by 30 to get 30 days. Make sure that you set the cookie before the `<HTML>` tag.

Comment: Hi @Martin, yes other pages being related to the website. How would i implement a 'session' variable? I will add the additional time code. Thanks

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Martin No not yet, close, but the issue is WP not remembering the session when I return to the page where I show/hide the content when i'm logged out. When i'm logged into the admin it all works fine!

Comment: Sounds like WordPress has its own way of dealing with sessions specifically. Try and have a look at this: https://www.ironistic.com/using-php-sessions-in-wordpress/ and see if you can make the sessions work. In the future, you should look to tag everything relevant to your question. WordPress for instance in this case. :)

Comment: The Session is working, when I visit the page with the url parameter, the hidden content is shown, but on returning to the page after visiting another on the same domain, the content is hidden. But if logged in, then it works as it should. I have tried the solution in that post as well as many more, but nothing is working, I think i may have to try and find a different way of doing what i need!

Answer (score 0):

Since you confirmed in the comment section that you are not leaving your own domain, You could put the `GET` variable into a `SESSION` variable and do your checks based on that. That way, you will always have that available to you until the user leaves the site or you manually kill the session somewhere.

**Example:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["client_feedback"] = $_GET['client_feedback'];
?>
```

As long as declare your `session_start();` at the very beginning of your page(s) (literally before ANYTHING else), you can access your session variable anywhere you want.

Now you can perform checks on your `session` variable with the logic you're trying to achieve in order to display your desired content.

**Full Example:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_GET['client_feedback'] != "") {
    $_SESSION["client_feedback"] = $_GET['client_feedback'];
}

if( isset( $_SESSION["client_feedback"] ) != "" ) {
    ?> <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:block!important}</style> <?php
} else {
    ?> <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:none!important}</style> <?php
}
?>
```

You can read more about PHP sessions [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Comment: Hi @Martin, I added your code above, adding to the page template and header.php (not at the same time), and whilst the session was showing in dev tools and also the cookie was hiding/showing the content as required, viewing another page and returning to the page with the cookie the content is hidden again. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not using cookies in my example, this is strictly sessions. If you do exactly as described, it should work. Simply declare `session_start();` at the beginning of the file where you wanna use the session.

Comment: Ok, I removed the cookie from functions.php and added the `session_start();` at the top of the php template file, again using **/?client_feedback=1** in the url shows the content, moving away and returning to the page the content is hidden. I guess i'm missing something!

Comment: The very first example in my answer is what you should do when a user first visits the page. I don't know if you have some sort of *header.php* or similar logic that you *include* in all of your files, but if you do, simply declare `session_start();` to carry over the session so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: I added `<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["client_feedback"] = $_GET['client_feedback'];
?>` in the header.php file

Comment: I then added `<?php

if( isset( $_SESSION["client_feedback"] ) != "" ) {
    ?> <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:block!important}</style> <?php
} else {
    ?> <style type="text/css">#form__feedback {display:none!important}</style> <?php
}
?>` into the page-template.php. Same happens, hidden content is shown with `/?client_feedback=1` url and returning to the page content is hidden again. Seems the session is not saving the url parameter so the css is not working to show/hide content when returning to the page.

Comment: One thing you should note is that you only need to declare the session variabe once, which is within the page that has the `GET` variable available. After that, as long as every page has `session_start();` the session will carry over and you will be able to access the session on any page you desire.

Comment: Added just `session_start();` in to the header.php and left the script with the `GET` variable in the page-template.php. still not working. This is Wordpress platform, will that make a difference. may have to look for an alternative solution!